# Regexp in Google Analytics funnel doesn't work

Tags: regex, google-analytics, e-commerce, cart

I need to check my abandoned cart size but I can't create good regexp.

My cart steps looks like this:

- /cart
- /cart2
- /cart3
- /cart4
- /thank-you

When I put this as is - I get ~75% leaves from /cart (step 1) and each next step has 100% "green" traffic :D

when I put something like this:

- ^/cart$
- ^/cart2$
- ^/cart3$
- ^/cart4$
- ^/thank-you$

I get traffic on level 0 - it's looks like nobody make purchase.
I even create something like this for first step: /cart(?![1-4])$ but it's give me nothing.

How to create good regexp for similar cart steps names to get real abandoned cart level and avoid backfill?

Comment: When using the start of string `^` anchor, you disallow anything before `cart`, and when using the end of string `$` you disallow matching the rest of the string. So, `something/cart2/rest-of-string` will not be matched with `^/cart$`, but will be matched with `/cart`. `/cart(?![1-4])$` does not make sense as end of string cannot be equal to a digit from 1 to 4. I suggest you place those rules in *reverse* order so that the longest would trigger first. GA does not support look-arounds anyway.

Comment: So, what if you set them up as `/thank-you`, `/cart4`, `/cart3`, `/cart2`, `/cart`? Or, say, `/thank-you`, `/cart[2-4]`, `/cart`?